# How to get the child view controller while doing custom animations in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have a root view controller which has a child view controller. 
I need to present a view controller from the child with a custom animation.

By using the default modal presentation style it presents perfectly fine. When using a custom animator I need a reference to the child controller from the transition context `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
  let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)
}
```

`toVC` is always the root controller instead of the child controller. 
Also did try setting the `definesPresentationContext` for the child controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another key for `viewController` in the `transitionContext`:

```
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)
    //...
}
```

Comment: My bad ! I had put in the `from` there. But my intention was `to` itself .. But with this I am actually getting a reference to the root controller and not the child from where it was actually presented.

Comment: I think you are messing up two conceptions: first is presenting and presented view controllers and second is parent and child view controllers. And custom transitions are not related to parent and child controllers, they operate with presenting and presented controllers